# Use QGIS or QField with a GPS physically walk a polygon in the field

Tags: qgis, polygon, gps, qfield

Is it possible to use QGIS or QField with a GPS to physically walk a polygon in the field?

I'd like to use the software to physically walk shapes in the field but have been unable to find information on how to do so.

Comment: If by "with a gps" you mean "with a handheld GPS unit" then you should find that functionality in the unit. Convert your polygon to a line (so it has a start point) then save for your GPS (GPX format, probably), and then tell your unit you want tot track it, and you should get heading and distances...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had meant I was hoping to have either QGIS or QField on a tablet in the field - whereby I am able to consult other data I have on the area. At this point I was hoping to create polygons of shapes I have physically walked, add attributes and edit as required in the field.

Comment: So you want to track your route and turn it into a polygon? Or did you want to use QGIS to guide you along the boundary of an already-mapped polygon?

Comment: I'd like to track my route and turn it into a polygon.

Answer (score 3):

Tracking your route and turning it into a point, line or polygon is possible in QField and is described in the [QField documentation how-to guide](https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/tracking/).

To activate tracking you must first activate positioning. You then long press on the legend layer within which you want to save your tracks to. Under 'Setup tracking' you can configure the parameters for your tracking session.  Hit 'Start tracking' to start your tracking session. To end tracking, you long press on the legend layer and hit 'Stop tracking'.
You can simultaneously use tracking across multiple layers.

For [positioning](https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/gnss/) you can either use the internal antenna of your mobile device or an external GNSS-Receiver.